# Creating View in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a View in Oracle which gets data based on the following conditions:

**Situation First:** In TABLE1 for the same CALLTICKET & ORDERNO there are 5 parts requested.
First four have been received and one is requested to Delete which sets the DEL_FLG 'D'.

```
    TABLE1
    ------------------------------------------------------
    CALLTICKET ORDERNO  PART_NO   RECEIVE_ETA   DEL_FLG
    123456     100900   ABC-123   09-02-2017       N
    123456     100900   ABC-121   09-02-2017       N      
    123456     100900   ABC-456   09-02-2017       N
    123456     100900   ABC-697   09-02-2017       N
    123456     100900   ABC-852                    D
```

**Situation Second:** In TABLE1 for the same CALLTICKET & ORDERNO there are 5 parts requested.
Two parts have been received, two are pending for delivery, and one is requested to Delete which sets the DEL_FLG 'D'.

```
    TABLE1
    ------------------------------------------------------
    CALLTICKET ORDERNO  PART_NO   RECEIVE_ETA   DEL_FLG
    123456     100900   ABC-123   09-02-2017       N
    123456     100900   ABC-121   09-02-2017       N      
    123456     100900   ABC-456                    D
    123456     100900   ABC-697                    N
    123456     100900   ABC-852                    N
```

Now I want to create a VIEW which SELECTs **only** those DISTINCT CALLTICKETs whose DEL_FLG is 'D' **but** rest of the parts are delivered i.e., RECEIVE_ETA IS NOT NULL (Like in Situation First), and unlike Situation Second which has one deleted PART_NO but delivery of two parts is still pending.

Please help me create a VIEW or a SELECT query for the specified condition.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't think he does; I'll edit PL out.

Comment: It would help if you add for your sample data the desired result.

Comment: OK, I think I understand the requirement. Are D and N the only possible values in `DEL_FLG` (and/or can it be `null`)? Also, do you need the tickets that have ALL FIVE PARTS delivered, and no row with `DEL_FLG=D`? And - is it always exactly five parts, or can some combinations of `CALLTICKET` and `ODERNO` have a different number of parts?

Comment: There can be different number of parts requested on a Call Ticket, this is just an example with five parts.
DEL_FLAG is set to 'N' by default. So only 'N' and 'D' works here.
My requirement is only to fetch the CallTicket which has 'D' in it but rest of the parts delivered.
Situation Two has 'D' in it but two parts are still pending for delivery, so it should not be fetched in the View.

Comment: Can you be bothered to answer all three questions I asked, or don't you have time for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the `calltickets` you can use aggregation:

```
select calltickets, orderno
from table1
group by calltickets, orderno
having sum(case when receive_eta is null and del_flag = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when del_flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The second condition is because you appear to want calltickets/orders that have at least one deleted row.

Comment: This will return also the calltickets with **no** rows with `DEL_FLG=D`. It seems from the OP's question that he is not interested in those. So: one can ask a question for clarification; or one can shoot now and ask questions later. (Or never.) Not good! ("Who has time for questions" - right?)

Answer (score 0):

This query will return records matching the criteria of the first situation and exclude records matching the criteria of the second situation :

```
select distinct callticket
       , orderno
from table1
where del_flg = 'D'
and (callticket, orderno) not in 
          ( select callticket, orderno
            from table1
            where del_flg != 'D'
            and receive_eta is null )
```

Depending on the number of records involved this might not be very efficient. However what is really required is a better data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS.

This query returns all rows with del_flg = 'D' and all RECEIVE_EXTA are not null

```
select * from table1 t1 where DEL_FLG = 'D'
and not exists (select 1 from table1 t2 where (t2.callticket=t1.callticket and t2.RECEIVE_EXTA IS NULL );
```

But there may be more than one record with del_flg='D'. What do you need in this case ? If you need just callticket you can do with

```
select distinct callticket from table1 t1 where DEL_FLG = 'D'
and not exists (select 1 from table1 t2 where (t2.callticket=t1.callticket and t2.RECEIVE_EXTA IS NULL );
```

If you know, as it looks like that ORDERNO  is unique for callticket, you can put it in the field list too.

But depending on your needs the query may become more articulate

Answer (score 0):

1. Inner Query -- Check for records with DEL_FLG = 'N' and received(RECEIVE_ETA is null). Here i'm using min function with group by function. It will select minimum receive date. If it is null, NVL function will assign receive date'1900-01-01'. If atleast a record have null value it will returun '1900-01-01'.
2. Outer Query -- With the help of above query fetch all records with DEL_FLG      = 'D' and all the records are received

   SELECT DISTINCT A.CALLTICKET
   FROM TABLE1 A,
     (SELECT CALLTICKET,
       MIN(NVL(RECEIVE_ETA,'1900-01-01')) RECEIVE_ETA
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE DEL_FLG = 'N'
     GROUP BY CALLTICKET
     ) B
   WHERE A.CALLTICKET = B.CALLTICKET
   AND A.DEL_FLG      = 'D'
   AND B.RECEIVE_ETA <> '1900-01-01'

Kindly let me know if you need more help on this.